# Folder name with space in SQL*Plus script

Tags: sql, linux, plsql, sqlplus

I wrote the following script to create a new folder

```
column mn new_value _mn;
select '\\common\jds\Daily report\DailyReport2017\\'||tochar(sysdate,'mon')||'\';
host mkdir &_mn;
```

but it throws error

> ```
> 'The specified path is invalid.
> Error occurred while processing \\common\jdfs\Daily',
> ```

since there is space in the name

How can I create the folder

Comment: Inside a string, double the single quotes to escape them. E.g. `'tochar(sysdate,''mon'')'`

Comment: Adding a database tag will help a lot.

Comment: I'm not near a Linux prompt right now, but try `host mkdir "&_mn";` i.e. double-quotes around the directory name. (Or single quotes if that fails. The `host` command might eat a layer of quotes.)

Answer (score 3):

Unlike in Windows, In Linux the default folder separator is the */* and the spaces must be escaped with a *backslash (\)*. Therefore I would try to use this instead:

```
select '/common/jds/Daily\ report/DailyReport2017/' || tochar(sysdate,'mon')  || '/';
```